# How to reject requests with apache that don't match list of vhosts

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I'm getting a ton of requests to my web application for ips without a host and hosts that don't matching anything I usually serve up.

I found a [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220519/how-to-disable-djangos-invalid-http-host-error) related to this but I'm not sure where to put this apache configuration (or if it's something I need to add to both my :80 and :443 configurations separately).

Here is what they show for reference. Note- this seems to only support a single host, how can I do this for 2 or 3 hosts?

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Host example\.com VALID_HOST  
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
Allow from env=VALID_HOST
```

Comment: Just an update for anyone who might follow -the above goes in your httpd.conf file under a directory listing. I was able to block wsgi and static requests using this approach

Answer (score 1):

Mod_Security may be what you are looking for. The default rules blocks this kind of requests, here is an example of a reconnaissance being blocked found in my debug logs:

Message: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Pattern match "^[\d.:]+$" at REQUEST_HEADERS:Host. [file "/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_21_protocol_anomalies.conf"] [line "98"] [id "960017"] [rev "2"] [msg "**Host header is a numeric IP address**"] [data "1.2.3.4"] [severity "WARNING"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/2.2.6"] [maturity "9"] [accuracy "9"] [tag "OWASP_CRS/**PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/IP_HOST**"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-21"] [tag "OWASP_TOP_10/A7"] [tag "PCI/6.5.10"] [tag "http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2005.01.hackerbasher.aspx"]

Comment: How do I enable it? Can I register a host name ?

Comment: It is not installed by default, you have to install it with your package manager. You don't need to register a host name, it would block any http request missing a valid host header or pointing directly to the IP address.

Comment: @ToranBillups Required Reading: http://www.modsecurity.org/documentation/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the NameVirtualHost feature, define a first `VirtualHost` (I usually name it with the same hostname of the system - if different than the one it's serving out the web app on - or to its numeric IP). Let it be empty and possibly `Deny from All`.

Then define another VirtualHost with the correct hostname that should be used for your site / app, and let it do its business.